# PowerShell - Overwrite existing alias, but tab completion isn't updated

Tags: alias, powershell-5.0

I overwrite the existing alias `ls` with an own function. It works, but the tab completion still shows the options of the build-in `Get-ChildItem` instead of the options from my function. If I change to a different alias, it works fine.

Here is a MWE:

```
Remove-Item alias:ls -Force
function global:Get-MyChildItems {
    param ([string]$filter)
    Get-ChildItem -Filter $filter
}
Set-Alias ls Get-MyChildItems
Set-Alias l Get-MyChildItems
```

Now I type `ls -` and press tab twice. You see the result here: [image: here]
It is the same list you get from the `Get-ChildItem`.

When typing `l -` and press tab, the option is completed with the only option my function has: `-filter`.

Why is the completion different?

I work with PSVersion 5.0.10586.117.

Comment: How are you resetting the alias?  Are you using `set-alias` ?

Comment: I added a MWE, does this answer your question?

Comment: According to the documentation on `Set-Alias` it should allow you to just overwrite `ls` without the need to `remove-item`.  I can't see that causing it though.  If you can record the evidence it might be worth seeking out how to report a bug, it's probably something people haven't tried to do very often.

Comment: Ok, here you see a screenshot from the changed `ls`. What is the result from the MWE on your computer?

Comment: Hmm strange, I'm on PSVersion 5.1.14393.1944  - if I run your code to replace the alias and then type `ls -` pressing tab 2x does nothing for me.  It just auto completes the `ls -filter` bit on the first press and thats it.

Comment: That is really strange. I have this issue on a Win 7 and a Win 10 machine. The later has PSVersion 5.1.16299.98.

Comment: Tried it on a Win 10 machine and a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, both on PowerShell v5.  
Win 10 = 5.1.14393.1944  
Server 2012 = 5.1.14409.1005  
  
Both had the same result as above.

Stupid question, but you are closing the ISE and not just letting it shutdown with windows?  It doesnt clear the environment properly if you don't close it and let it close with a windows shutdown.

Comment: There are no stupid questions. :) I tried it in the ISE, and everything was fine. But the behaviour in the console is different. Did it work in your console as I described it?

Comment: Yup you are 100% right, in the console it doesnt work correctly.  I have no idea how you do it but this probably needs reporting to Microsoft.  ISE works fine, console doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion, where to send a bug report?

Comment: I have no idea sorry, it used to be on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) but they retired that.  I can't find it on the place it forwards you too :(